# Why @use and @include works in global scss file but not components scss files?

Tags: sass, next.js, scss-mixins

## Context

I'm using `NextJS v12.1.0`, `React v17.0.2` and `sass v1.49.9`.

I'm trying to create a theme switcher based on [that article](https://medium.com/@katiemctigue/how-to-create-a-dark-mode-in-sass-609f131a3995).
My folder structure is like that :

```
myProject
└───src
|   └───styles
│   │   _color-themes.scss // Themes and themed() mixin + t($key) function
│   │   _colors.scss // Colors variables
│   │   globals.scss // My global app style
│   │
│   └───components
│   |   └───my-component
│   |   │   index.tsx
│   |   │   MyComponent.module.scss // My component style
```

I'm using that part of code in `globals.scss` which is working well :

```scss
@use "src/styles/color-themes" as *;

#content {
  padding: 48px 80px;
  @include themed() {
    background-color: t($bg); // Property is applied
  }
}
```

But when I'm using it in `MyComponent.module.scss` the SCSS added property is not applied to the rendered element :

```scss
@use "src/styles/color-themes" as *;

$border-radius: 8px;
$shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 5px 15px;

.input {
  font-size: 1rem; // Applied well
  padding: 24px 74px; // Applied well
  width: 476px; // Applied well
  border: none; // Applied well
  border-radius: $border-radius; // Applied well
  box-shadow: $shadow; // Applied well
  @include themed() {
    color: t($input); // Property is never applied
  }
}
```

## My problem

The `color` property is never applied to my elements, even if others properties I'm adding outside the `themed()` are applied. I've also tried to use `t($bg)` and that's not applied too.

Here is the only applied properties (defined in MyComponent.module.scss):

[image: Screenshot of applied properties (input class)]

And here is the well applied property (defined in globals.scss):
[image: Screenshot of well applied property (content id)]

I've done researches and I can't find any case like me on Google or Stackoverflow, I'm new in SCSS so I'm probably misunderstanding something. Does someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly came to a solution in [that Denis Pasin's article](https://www.zaratan.fr/next-refactor-theme-scss).

So I just needed to update create two mixins:
`themed` for components style
`gthemed` for globals style

```scss
@mixin themed() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        :global(.theme--#{$theme}) & {
            $theme-map: () !global;
            @each $key, $submap in $map {
                $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), "#{$key}");
                $theme-map: map-merge(
                    $theme-map,
                    (
                        $key: $value,
                    )
                ) !global;
            }
            @content;
            $theme-map: null !global;
        }
    }
}
```

```scss
@mixin gthemed() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        .theme--#{$theme} & {
            $theme-map: () !global;
            @each $key, $submap in $map {
                $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), "#{$key}");
                $theme-map: map-merge(
                    $theme-map,
                    (
                        $key: $value,
                    )
                ) !global;
            }
            @content;
            $theme-map: null !global;
        }
    }
}
```